# Google Ads - Google GPT Exception invoking function: Object 73 has no method ‘join’

Tags: google-ads-api, google-dfp

Ran in to this issue while trying to implement the new DFP tag. I noticed this when for a certain slot, the ads were not rendering. One can see this in the google ad console which can be forced to open by appending google_force_console=1 to the url.

This is causing the ad to not render even though all the slots and display code is correctly added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://www.johnish.com/2013/09/17/google-gpt-exception-invoking-function-object-73-has-no-method-join/)

Solution is Look out for if you are passing any integer as a value since GPT only supports string.

Additionally the article also mentions a nice utility called Charles for Mac which looks like a good alternative to jsfiddle.